# ReactJS: How to handle component state when it's based on AJAX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Summary:** New to ReactJS and I'm trying to figure out the best way to update a component when it's state depends on a remote API (i.e. keep component state in sync with remote database via AJAX API).

**Example Use Case:** Think of a product inventory where clicking a button adds a product to your cart and decrements the inventory by 1. Every time the user clicks it initiates an AJAX request and then upon completion of the request, the component re-renders with the new product inventory by calling `setState()`.

**Problem:** I've ran into an issue where because both `setState()` and the AJAX request are asynchronous, the component becomes out of the sync with the server. For example if you click really quickly you can initiate more than one AJAX request for a single product ID because the component's state has not yet updated to reflect that the product ID is no longer in inventory. I have a simple example below to illustrate the concept:

**Inadequate Solution:** This could be handled on the server side by sending an error back if the client request a product that is no longer in inventory, however I'm really looking for the best way to handle this common scenario in ReactJS on the client side and to make sure I'm understanding the best way to handle component state.

```
Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clicksLeft: 0,
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    //getClicksLeft is async and takes a callback, think axios/superagent
    getClicksLeft((response) => { 
      this.setState(response);
    });
  }
  btnClicked = () => {
    //This may appear redundant/useless but 
    //imagine sending an element in a list and then requesting the updated 
    //list back
    const data = {clicks: this.state.clicksLeft--};
    decrementClicksLeft(data, () => {
      getClicksLeft((response) => { 
        this.setState(response);
      });     
    }
  }
  render() {
    <button onClick={this.btnClicked}>Click me {this.state.clicksLeft} times</button>
  }
}
```

Comment: Part of the answer here is opinion-based. Projects like [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) solve this problem, and it's worth reading how they do it. The more objective part of the answer is that React components should not house asynchronous work; they should only do synchronous work. This is why the [`isMounted` function](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html) was removed from React.

Comment: Sounds like you just need a better store to manage the transactions. [Relay](https://facebook.github.io/relay/) can also handle this for you, though it's learning curve is insane.

Comment: The app I'm working on is fairly small so I was trying to avoid the learning cover of something like redux. If what you're saying is those types of libraries (flux implementations basically?) were to solve this specific problem then I suppose I have no choice. At least now I have a compelling reason to learn one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time with react-redux, redux-thunk and redux-pack I decided to go with something simpler: [react-refetch](https://github.com/heroku/react-refetch). I didn't really need the complexities of redux as I am only doing post and get operations on lists. I also need some simple side effects like when I do a post, I need to update multiple lists (which is achieved through `andThen()` in react-refetch).

This solution has much less boiler plate and works great for small projects. The core reason to choose this project over react-redux can be summarized in this quote from heroku's [blog entry](https://engineering.heroku.com/blogs/2015-12-16-react-refetch/):

> Looking around for alternatives, Redux was the Flux-like library du jour, and it did seem very promising. We loved how the React Redux bindings used pure functions to select state from the store and higher-order functions to inject and bind that state and actions into otherwise stateless components. We started to move down the path of standardizing on Redux, but there was something that felt wrong about loading and reducing data into the global store only to select it back out again. This pattern makes a lot of sense when an application is actually maintaining client-side state that needs to be shared between components or cached in the browser, but when components are just loading data from a server and rendering it, it can be overkill.

1: https://github.com/heroku/react-refetch

2: https://engineering.heroku.com/blogs/2015-12-16-react-refetch/

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason to have to call `getClicksLeft` when the button is clicked? You have already called it when the component is mounted and then anytime the button is clicked you just decrement that number by one.

```
btnClicked = () => {
  if (this.state.clicksLeft > 0) {
    decrementClicksLeft();    
    this.setState({clicksLeft: this.state.clicksLeft - 1});
  }
}
```

This would work if there is only one user trying to buy stuff at a time. Otherwise you could also check the amount left before making the purchase.

```
btnClicked = () => {
  getClicksLeft((response) => { 
    if (response > 0) {
      decrementClicksLeft();
      this.setState({clicksLeft: this.state.clicksLeft - 1});
    }
  });     
}
```

This way if there are no clicks left, nothing happens.

Comment: You nailed the reason to call the remote API to getClickdLeft() or more practically get products left in inventory: what if more than one person is accessing that remote data source at the same time? Then the component's internal state is not authoritative.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic solution would be to disable the button while you wait for the response to come back:

(I've also made your code simpler.)

```
Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Initial state
    this.state = {
      clicksLeft: 0, // No clicks are availabe
      makeRequest: false, // We are not asking to make a request to the server
      pendingTransaction: false, // There is no current request out to the server
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Initial load completed, so go get the number of clicks
    this._getClicksRemaining();
  }

  // Called whenever props/state change
  // NOT called for the initial render
  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    // If there is no existing request out to the server, AND if the next
    // state is asking us to make a request (as set in _handleButtonClick)
    // then go make the request
    if (!this.state.pendingTransaction && nextState.makeRequest) {
      const data = {
        clicks: this.state.clicksLeft--,
      };

      // decrementClicksLeft is async
      decrementClicksLeft(data, () => this._getClicksRemaining());

      // First fire off the async decrementClicksLeft request above, then
      // tell the component that there is a pending request out, and that it
      // is not allowed to try and make new requests
      // NOTE this is the one part of the code that is vulnerable to your
      // initial problem, where in theory a user could click the button
      // again before this setState completes. However, if your user is able
      // to do that, then they are probably using a script and you shouldn't
      // worry about them. setState/render is very fast, so this should be
      // more than enough protection against human clicking
      this.setState({
        makeRequest: false,
        pendingTransaction: true,
      });
    }
  }

  _getClicksRemaining() {
    // getClicksLeft is async
    getClicksLeft((response) => { 
      // Here we are inside of the callback from getClicksLeft, so we 
      // know that it has completed. So, reset our flags to show that 
      // there is no request still pending
      const newState = Object.assign(
        {
          pendingTransaction: false,
        },
        response,
      );

      this.setState(newState);
    }); 
  }

  // The button was clicked
  _handleButtonClick = () => {
    if (!this.state.pendingTransaction) {
      // If there isn't a request out to the server currently, it's safe to
      // make a new one. Setting state here will cause `componentWillUpdate`
      // to get called
      this.setState({
        makeRequest: true,
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    // Disable the button if:
    //   * there are no clicks left
    //   * there is a pending request out to the server
    const buttonDisabled = ((this.state.clicksLeft === 0) || this.state.pendingTransaction);

    return (
      <button
        disabled={buttonDisabled}
        onClick={this._handleButtonClick}
      >
        Click me {this.state.clicksLeft} times
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response I can't believe I didn't think of disabling the button haha. Would you mind explaining how your code is simpler or editing in some comments to show what you're doing and why? I'm new to React and am having trouble following exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I've commented all the code. Please let me know if you have questions. I made it simpler mostly by putting the `getClicksLeft` method in a helper function and then calling that function, so that you don't need to define the callbacks multiple times.